# Is there any way to override the -fvisibility=hidden at link time？

Tags: android, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, compiler-flags

We are using an third party static library, let say `A.a` for android development. We link it as shared library and it works fine in the one App, but when use `B.so` to build another `C.so`, some symbols in `A.a` cannot find. We have already use `-Wl,--export-dynamic` and `-Wl,--whole-archive` to build `B.so`. We have using `nm` to check those symbols, it exist but list as `“t”` instead of `“T”`，which means it is local symbols instead of external. Seams the `A.a` are build with `-fvisibility=hidden` after som investigation.

But because some reason it is hard for us to got an new build library immediately, so we need some workaround. Is there any way to export those symbols as global even it has been build with `-fvisibility=hidden` in `B.so` at link time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have using nm to check those symbols

You shouldn't: on ELF platforms, `nm` is *inadequate* for the job. Use `readelf -Ws` instead.

> it exist but list as “t” instead of “T”，which means it is local symbols instead of external. Seams the A.a are build with -fvisibility=hidden after som investigation.

Your conclusion does not follow: there are *many* reasons a symbol may show up as a `t`. Being compiled with `-fvisibility=hidden` is only one of many possibilities.

> Is there any way to export those symbols as global even it has been build with `-fvisibility=hidden`

The symbol table is just a linear table of `Elf{32,64}_Sym[]`s. You can find the start of this table in the object file with `readelf -WS foo.o | grep '\.symtab'`, find the number of offending symbol from `readelf -Ws`, and find the offset of the symbol in the `foo.o` by combining the two:

```
sym-offset = .symtab offset + (sym-number * sizeof(Sym))
```

Once you have the offset, you can override its `.st_info` with `STV_DEFAULT` (if your theory is correct and you located the symbol correctly, you should find `STV_HIDDEN` there currently).

Once you've patched your `foo.o`, the symbol will no longer be hidden, and when you link `foo.o` into `B.so`, it will be global / exported.

Comment: "Once you've patched your foo.o, the symbol will no longer be hidden" - don't we need to update the hash table as well?

Comment: @yugr "once you've patched `foo.o`, when you link `foo.o` into `B.so` it will be exported" -- the linker will build the new hash table.

Comment: I see, thanks. I wonder if hashtab could be patched as well (for a more realistic usecase of already linked shlib).

Comment: I've added a draft tool at https://github.com/yugr/SymbolHider . It seems to work for  linked shlibs as well which is an important usecase. I'd appreciate your review/comments on proposed solution.

Comment: (the tool is for hiding symbols of course as unhiding them would require a non-trivial patching of `.dynsym` and hashtables which is probly unrealistic)