# Modify visibility of symbol in compiled shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, visibility, elf

My project depends of a third-party library that exports more symbols that it should. Some of those symbols are being, not intentionally, overwritten by other libraries and the main program.

How can I change the visibility of functions and variables of a compiled shared object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can load the problematic library dynamically via `dlopen` you may use the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag to force it to prefer local symbols to the ones in main executable or other shlibs.

If you don't want to manage `dlopen` and `dlsym` calls manually, you can create a simple wrapper file which would contain trampolines for necessary functions. Each trampoline would internally `dlopen` the library if it hasn't been loaded before and forward the call to `dlsym`-ed symbol with same name. Such wrapper file can be generated automatically via [Implib.so tool](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so#reducing-external-interface-of-closed-source-library).

Comment: I think answer of @EmployedRussian is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change the visibility of functions and variables of a compiled shared object?

You could change visibility of symbols by modifying the dynamic symbol section (`.dynsym`) -- it contains a flat array of `Elf32_Sym`s or `Elf64_Sym`s, and you can overwrite the `.st_info` and `.st_other` fields in it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274814/50617)).

I am not aware of any tools that would make this simple, you would likely have to write a custom program to do this.

Comment: "I am not aware of any tools that would make this simple" - there is https://github.com/yugr/SymbolHider now.

Answer (score 0):

Following EmployedRussian's advice, I've made a simple tool [SymbolHider](https://github.com/yugr/SymbolHider) to patch the dynamic section of the executable:

```
$ sym-hider libmy.so sym1 sym2 ...
```

It can also be applied to object files.