# Same function name in a shared library and a static library that a project link to

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am building my project in C++. I have these two libraries: shared_lib1 and static_lib2. Both have a function with the same name as func(). Only func() in static_lib2 has an assert statement. shared_lib1 is a shared library and static_lib2 is a static library.

and lib3 has dependency on shared_lib1.

I can't change any of these two libs: shared_lib1, static_lib2, because they are third-party libraries. lib3 is available either as a dynamic library or a static library.

I use lib3 as a shared library: shared_lib3. When this shared_lib3 was built, ldd command shows its dependency on shared_lib1. So I think shared_lib3 should use func() in shared_lib1.

In my project, it links to both shared_lib3 and static_lib2, and src1.cpp calls a function func3() in shared_lib3, which is supposed to call func() in shared_lib1, but the program aborted with a core dump and the backtrace shows it aborted because of the assert statement in func() from static_lib2.

Comment: The only way shared_lib3 could call something from static_lib2 is if they were linked together. Once those are linked it will never even look for the other definition.

Comment: What is your question? If it's "how to unscrew this situation up", then there is no way other than changing one or more of the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I think shared_lib3 should use `func()` in shared_lib1.

That is *not* how shared libraries work on UNIX. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897619/50617).

When you link `static_lib2` into the main executable, the `func()` defined there gets to the head of the queue, and will be used to resolve *all* calls to `func()` *regardless* of where these calls come from. This is one of the major differences between UNIX shared libraries and windows DLLs.

There are a few things you may try to fix this symbol collision problem.

If you are using Linux or another ELF platform, you may be able to "hide" the `func()` symbol in the main executable. See [man objcopy](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html) and `--localize-symbol`. This will work if nothing calls `func()` outside the `.o` file (part of `static_lib2`) which defines that function.

If that doesn't work, you could try to turn the `func()` definition into a HIDDEN symbol (which will prevent it from being exported from the main executable). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124458/50617) and the answer it references.

If that doesn't work, `objcopy` can also rename the `func()` symbol to a different name -- see `--redefine-sym` flag.