# Reduce exported symbols of a third party library

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I have code that works fine, but if I link my project to a third party lib `libabc.so` (source unavailable), then all of the sudden I get a segmentation fault.

I have a main that looks like this

```cpp
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "Abc.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Abc dummyAbc;
    auto img = cv::imread("dummy.png");
    cv::imwrite("123.png", img);
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeList.txt is as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
find_package(OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgcodecs)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(my_project Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_project ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} abc)
```

This compiles well, but segfault when running. If I remove the line

```cpp
Abc dummyAbc;
```

then all works fine (i.e. there is no problem with missing file, or opencv).

If I inspect the stack of the segfault, I see that:

```
Thread 1 "my_project" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fdea96836b3 in png_destroy_write_struct () from /usr/local/lib/libabc.so
```

where `png_destroy_write_struct` is being called by `cv::imwrite`.

Both `libpng.so` and `libabc.so` (!!) export `png_destroy_write_struct` it actually exports all of the libpng API (which I assume it was statically linked to?). I **assume** this is the problem? I do no want openCV to *see* whatever `libabc.so` exports... How can I do this?

I tried to use `objcopy --prefix-symbols abc_ libabc.so` but somehow it did not help, now the crash happens at `abc_png_destroy_write_struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume this is the problem?

Yes: that is very likely: `libabc.so` has statically linked (probably different version of) `libpng`, and introduces symbol conflict.

> I do no want openCV to see whatever libabc.so exports... How can I do this?

You can't. You must contact `libabc.so` developer, and tell them to *hide* `libpng` symbols.

The only other option (for single process execution) is to dynamically load `libabc.so`.

This can be done via `dlopen("liabc.so.", RTLD_LOCAL)`, and even that may not work (depending on exactly how `libabc.so` was linked) -- it may cause `libabc.so` to bind to your version of `libpng`, and crash.

On Linux, you could also possibly use `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libabc.so", ...)` which will *completely* isolate `libabc.so` from the rest of your code, and *may* work if `libabc.so` was linked to include all of its dependencies (or you can bring them into the new loader namespace explicitly).

Finally, as Eljay commented here, you could use inter-process communication and have a completely separate process load `libabc.so`. This will have much worse performance than using `libabc.so` directly, but is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible somehow to create my wrapper around `libabc.so` so that I manually hide/expose some of the methods (say, only the ones in "abc.h") and link against this new wrapper?

Comment: @AlWld "Would it be possible ...". No.

Comment: It would be possible, but it involves running it out-of-process and using interprocess communication.

Comment: Why not mention manual modification of `.dynsym` as mentioned in your [other answer](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so#reducing-external-interface-of-closed-source-library)?

Comment: @yugr The other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273404/is-there-any-way-to-override-the-fvisibility-hidden-at-link-time/36274814#36274814) only applies when you can relink the `.so`. Modifying `.so` itself is likely to cause the hash tables to become inconsistent, causing a crash in `ld-linux`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to EmployedRussian's answer about using `dlmopen`-based approach to isolate libabc.so from the rest of your code: to avoid messing with `dlsym` and function pointers in that case you could automatically generate wrappers for needed library functions via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so#reducing-external-interface-of-closed-source-library):

```
$ cat mysymbols.txt
foo
bar
$ cat mycallback.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

// Dlopen callback that loads library to dedicated namespace
void *mycallback() {
  void *h = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libabc.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
  if (h)
    return h;
  fprintf(stderr, "dlmopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
  exit(1);
}

$ implib-gen.py --dlopen-callback=mycallback --symbol-list=mysymbols.txt libabc.so
$ ... # Link your app with libabc.tramp.S, libabc.init.c and mycallback.c
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try `strip`. See this for details: https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip

Comment: `strip` does *nothing* for dynamic symbol tables.